# How to get image of configurable product?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, image

How can I get image of configurable product.
I found this code but it returns null

```
$_swatchUrl = Mage::helper('configurableswatches/productimg');
```

Answer (score 1):

The methods available in the helper you mentioned allows you to retrieve the image urls for the configurable swatches. For example the url of pink/white/blue swatch url for a super attribute such as color (ex: media/catalog/swatches/1/21x21/media/pink.png).
You can check in `.../configurable/swatches.phtml` how is being used
by the core: 
`$_swatchUrl = Mage::helper('configurableswatches/productimg')
 ->getSwatchUrl($_product, $_option->label, $_swatchInnerWidth, $_swatchInnerHeight, $_swatchType);`

But you want to take the image of a parent/configurable product so just follow the code from `.../catalog/product/view/media.phtml` 
`src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image') ?>"`

 which is retrieving the image of the product in the product view/page. 
**Note**: above sample of codes were taken from **Magento ver. 1.9.2.4**